# Mustache.js loop through JSON data

Tags: json, mustache

Can anyone advise how should my template loop like to loop through JSON data in following example? 
**DEMO here: http://jsfiddle.net/Seefeld/LbVEH/**

```
 {
    "0": {
        "Dosage": "25",
        "Drug": "Indocin",
        "Patient": "David",
        "Date": "15/11/2012 14:29:14"
    },
    "1": {
        "Dosage": "50",
        "Drug": "Enebrel",
        "Patient": "Sam",
        "Date": "15/11/2012 14:29:14"
    },
    "2": {
        "Dosage": "10",
        "Drug": "Hydralazine",
        "Patient": "Christoff",
        "Date": "15/11/2012 14:29:14"
    },
    "3": {
        "Dosage": "21",
        "Drug": "Combivent",
        "Patient": "Janet",
        "Date": "15/11/2012 14:29:14"
    },
    "4": {
        "Dosage": "100",
        "Drug": "Dilantin",
        "Patient": "Melanie",
        "Date": "15/11/2012 14:29:14"
    }
}
```

All examples I have seen on `mustache.js` assumed  that you know the object name.
**Any suggestion much appreciated.**

Comment: I suppose that you can't change the format of the JSON data?

Comment: I can on JS site, not the server side. What would you suggest?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can either transform `data` into a genuine array (which it should be anyway):

```
var drugs = [];
for (var i = 0, drug; (drug = data[i]); ++i) {
  drugs.push(drug);
}

var template = "{{#drugs}}<p>{{Drug}}</p>{{/drugs}}";
var html = Mustache.to_html(template, {drugs: drugs});
$(html).appendTo("#cnt");
```

or browse the data yourself:

```
var template = "<p>{{Drug}}</p>";
for (var i = 0, drug; (drug = data[i]); ++i) {
  var html = Mustache.to_html(template, drug);
  $(html).appendTo("#cnt");
}
```

Comment: - this approche works perfectly.  Can you suggest a way on transforming the data to real array on client site?

Comment: Many thanks! Slightly off topic, what is the purpose of 2nd parameter in `for loop`?

Comment: It it just a fancy way to write `for (var i = 0; data[i]; ++i) { var drug = data[i]; …`

Comment: @JulienRoyer its look like briliant solution but how about  {{> next_more}} inside of collection template what is defined on gtihup pages https://github.com/janl/mustache.js/

Comment: @NuriYILMAZ don’t hesitate to create a new answer, mine is probably obsolete and I don’t know much about Mustache. :-)