# Iterating over Roots in ICanHaz.js / Mustache

Tags: javascript, jquery, mustache, icanhaz.js

I'm running into an issue with iteration using ICanHaz.js / Mustache. I want to loop over the roots of a JSON structure and pull out a specific parameter. Here is my JSON:

```
{
"1": {
    "param1": "true",
    "param2": "false",
    "param3": "false",
    "targetMe": "ADMINUSERS"
},
"2": {
    "param1": "true",
    "param2": "false",
    "param3": "false",
    "targetMe": "ADMINUSERS"
},
"3": {
    "param1": "true",
    "param2": "false",
    "param3": "false",
    "targetMe": "ADMINUSERS"
}
}
```

Here is my ICanHaz Template:

```
<script id="groupselect_template" type="text/html">
     {{ /. }}
        <option value="{{name}}">{{name}}</option>
     {{ /. }}
</script>
```

And here is my JS:

```
var iterationFunc = function(data) {
var temp = ich.groupselect_template(data);
$('#selectdiv').append(temp);
```

}

I based this structure off of these past answers ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11891123/mustache-js-iterate-over-a-list-received-via-json), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11819006/mustache-js-template-with-json-collection) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13399816/mustache-js-loop-through-json-data)), but I can't seem to get it to work. Can anyone help? Since ICH has mustache inside of it, I know a broader mustache-based solution can work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't loop through object properties easily in moustache. But you can do it through array, so if you can, change your JSON to something like

```
[{
    "param1": "true",
    "param2": "false",
    "param3": "false",
    "targetMe": "ADMINUSERS"
},{
    "param1": "true",
    "param2": "false",
    "param3": "false",
    "targetMe": "ADMINUSERS"
},{
    "param1": "true",
    "param2": "false",
    "param3": "false",
    "targetMe": "ADMINUSERS"
}]
```

or before applying data to template, iterate through it and change it to array, for example using jQuery

```
var dataArray = [];
$.each(data, function(key, item){
    dataArray.push(item);
});
```

[Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/Y8XBj/3/) a working Fiddle